# toFixed без округления

Tags: javascript

Нужно оставить 4 символа после точки в float. Число `number = 0.00028`

`number.toFixed(4);` возвращает `0.0003`. Мне нужно чтобы число не округлялось. Есть ли в js что-то готовое на такой случай? Или нужно функцию писать?

Comment: Придётся написать

Answer (score 2):

[источник](https://helloacm.com/javascripts-tofixed-implementation-without-rounding/)

```js
Number.prototype.toFixedNoRounding = function(n) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`^-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,${n}})?`, 'g')
  const a = this.toString().match(reg)[0];
  const dot = a.indexOf('.');

  if (dot === -1) {
    return a + '.' + '0'.repeat(n);
  }

  const b = n - (a.length - dot) + 1;

  return b > 0 ? (a + '0'.repeat(b)) : a;
}

console.log((3.1999).toFixedNoRounding(3)); // 3.199
console.log((3.19923413412349).toFixedNoRounding(3)); // 3.199
console.log((3.01).toFixedNoRounding(3)); // 3.010
console.log((3.01).toFixedNoRounding(4)); // 3.0100
console.log((3.01).toFixedNoRounding(5)); // 3.01000
console.log((3).toFixedNoRounding(3)); // 3.000
console.log((-3).toFixedNoRounding(3)); // -3.000
console.log((0.00028).toFixedNoRounding(4)); // 0.0002
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(
(0.00028).toFixed(5).replace(/.$/,'') // 0.0002
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function toFixedHard(number, x) {
  return parseFloat(number.toFixed(x + 1).slice(0, -1));
}

console.log( toFixedHard(0.2, 0) );
console.log( toFixedHard(0.128, 1) );
console.log( toFixedHard(0.228, 2) );
console.log( toFixedHard(0.4428, 3) );
console.log( toFixedHard(0.00028, 4) );
console.log( toFixedHard(0.000280003974, 11) );
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
const toFixedHard = (number, x) => {
    const s = String(number)
    let [ a, b = '' ] = s.split('.')
    return parseFloat(a + '.' + b.substring(0, x))
}

console.log( toFixedHard(6.997, 1) ); // 6.9
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]